# Error in 2d vector c++

Tags: c++

I keep getting an out of range error when I try to populate a 2d vector in c++. Where am I going wrong? Posted below is a shortened version of my problem that I believe generates the same problem.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<double> NA;
typedef std::vector<NA> NB;

NA NI;
NB NO;

long i=0,j=0;
int N = 10;
double R;

int main(){

    for(i=0;i!=N;i++){

       NO.push_back(NI);
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){

            R = rand();


            NO.at(i).push_back(j);
            NO.at(i).at(j) = R;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no 2D vectors in your code. Also when you get "an error" its always useful to post the actual error message. (P.S: NI, NO, i, j, N, R are not very good variable names, consider using descriptive ones)

Comment: This: `NO.at(i).at(j) = R;` shouldn't compile? In fact it doesn't: http://ideone.com/ukPags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your typedefs are wrong. You mean:

   ```
   typedef std::vector<double> NA;
   typedef std::vector<NA> NB;
   //                  ^^
   ```
2. Your loop indexes are wrong. You mean `j++`.
3. The inner index must be offset: `at(j - i - 1)`.
4. The outer container update, `NO.push_back(NI);`, needs to move into the outer loop.

Comment: I don't get how the out of range error even came up. The code provided doesn't even compile? http://ideone.com/ukPags

Comment: [Full demo](http://ideone.com/8kBb31)

Comment: Sorry I wrote this on my phone as I don't have internet, let me correct these issues. Apologies.